# Remove cookie by indexOf values only.. not other values

Tags: jquery

Created the cookie - cookie1 & cookie2 to store in browser.

i want to delete this cookie, if url doesn't have indexOf - "test1" or "test2" (test1, test2 - different page parameters).

Used below code, but it picks only indexOf('test1) and removes cookie.. which affects test2 page.

**JS:**

```
$.cookie('cookie1', 1, { path: '/'});
$.cookie('cookie2', 2, { path: '/' });


if ((window.location.href.indexOf('test1') == -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf('test2') < 0))   
{
   $.removeCookie('cookie1', { path: '/' });
   $.removeCookie('cookie2', { path: '/' });
}
```

Please provide some hint how to define if logic for the requirement. If indexof - test1 or test2 not exists in any of the page, remove cookie.

Thanks

Comment: Be consistent and use && 
`if (window.location.href.indexOf('test1') == -1 && window.location.href.indexOf('test2') == -1)   ...`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply down to you using `||` where you mean `&&`:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf('test1') == -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf('test2') < 0))
{
    ...
```

This essential says if the page is not `test1` **OR** not `test2`, delete the cookie.

What you want is to use:

```
if ((window.location.href.indexOf('test1') == -1) && (window.location.href.indexOf('test2') < 0))
{
     ...
```

This will instead only execute if the page is not `test1` **AND** is not `test2`.

Incidentally, I would recommend using `includes` instead of `indexOf` (which determines if a string contains the specified value):

```
if (!window.location.href.includes('test1') && !window.location.href.includes('test2'))
{
     ...
```

**Edit following @mplungjan comment**

As pointed out, `includes` is not available in IE (although it is in Edge).  You can continue to use your `indexOf` solution if you need IE support, or use the recommended polyfill.  The link to this is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill).

Comment: Voted to close as typo-type

Comment: `includes` is not supported by IE and needs a polyfill